# Error When Publishing .NetCore Angular 6 to Azure

Tags: angular, azure, angular6, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an application that is running fine locally but gives an error when running in an Azure AppService:

InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\node_modules\start\package.json'

I can provide much more information if anyone thinks they can help.

Comment: You are trying to start angular app in dev mode on Azure ?

Comment: is that the problem, hod do I put in release mode?

Comment: Run the `ng build --prod` it will generate compiled static files in a dist directory, then you can expose the static files like any other static files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is about angular routes and service could not recognize them.

Have you created webconfig file ?

I had the same error and be able to fix it like

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*NEWPDS.*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                     <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
                </rule>

            </rules>
            <outboundRules>

            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

When using IIS.

Comment: I tried adding one in the root of my.csProj.  Same error I'm afraid

Comment: You have to declare that you are using a web config file to angular cli like ;"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "images",
        "favicon.ico",
        "web.config"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",

Comment: I found a tutorial and think I need to follow it through as the the angular.json file I have looks quite different to yours.

Comment: Thanks Kutlu, Your advice was good.  I started again and this worked :)